# Cannot insert the value NULL into column '', table 'Orders'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Every time I run `update-database`, this error is thrown. I have tried to add `computed` annotations to the `datetime` properties, but that did not work.

Here is my class:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int orderid { get; set; }
    public long tuid { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime created { get; set; }

    public DateTime? completed { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string product { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }

    [Required, System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(OrderStatus.Pending)]
    public OrderStatus status { get; set; } = OrderStatus.Pending;

    public void Save()
    {
        Program.OrderRepository.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'completed', table 'Orders'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

This error is likely thrown when I have multiple datetimes. `completed` property should be `null` as a default, and it should allow null as my code requirement.

Comment: Seems like `completed` should be nullable. Are you sure you're not doing any other configuration, such as in `OnModelCreating()`?

Comment: It's fixed by re-creating the database im really bored of this chronic issues about dbcontext... now im facing with very similar issue.

Comment: I don't have any issues like this. It works rock solid for me. You may have other issues going on. Or you're making changes and not adding migrations correctly.